# How to disable tooltips in kendo ui grids and slider?

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

How can I disable tooltips in kendo ui grids and slider?
I've tried to slider:

```
var slider = $('#selector').kendoSlider({
    tooltip: {enabled: false}
}).data("kendoSlider");
```

But It isn't disabled. 
I would like to know how to disable grid tooltips also.

Kendo ui version:  2012.3.1114

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `tooltip` in a slider is for the value of the slider and that works as you have defined. If what you want is remove *title* of the drag handler and the increase / decrease buttons, then you should use:

```
var slider = $("#slider").kendoSlider({
    increaseButtonTitle: "",
    decreaseButtonTitle: "",
    dragHandleTitle:""
}).data("kendoSlider");
```

Comment: And, Do you know how disable or change grids tooltips?

Comment: Which ones? Pageable are here http://docs.kendoui.com/api/web/grid#pageablemessages-object. Which others?

Comment: @OnaBai - the `dragHandleTitle` property doesn't seem to do anything on the Kendo slider, FYI (at least in Kendo UI Web, not the MVC edition).

Comment: @nickb, in my environment it does... place the mouse over the handle and wait a few seconds, it displays the message that you define for it.

Comment: @OnaBai Strange, I just get `undefined` in the browser tooltip in Chrome & FF/Win7 with that property set. Are you using the Kendo UI Web Q1 2013 release?

Comment: @nickb I had the same behavior when I was using a <div> tag to host the control instead of a <input> tag.

Answer (score 0):

Using an `<input>` tag instead of a `<div>` will resolve the `undefined` issue on the draggable tip of the slider. Additionally, `dragHandleTitle:""` property for `kendoSlider` can also be used to remove the default value `drag` from the tip